# Stretching layout for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm not sure how to achieve the below layout using CSS and HTML only and make the `divs` stretch when the viewport is resized.
This interface is for a cross-mobile app.

I've done the stretching part by using CSS only and images will fill the `divs` by using JS. I just need to know what's the best way to achieve this grid sort of layout using CSS and HTML.
[image]

Or if someone knows a good css boilerplate to start with (for mobile sites) - I'd also like to note that I'm using jQuery Mobile for this.

### Edit:

Since i'm using JQM I am currently updating the design and it seems to work. Great reference: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Will update in a bit.

Comment: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Explain your picture a bit.

Comment: I would stay away from those grids if I were you. Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/JwxAs    - I can't tell what your image is supposed to show as far as how you want it to be responsive. The answer to your question is That you should use `@media` rules and percentages. The top ones are 50%; the bottom ones are 25%. Make your images img {display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; } so they resize to the box since it might "Stretch."

Comment: @sheriffderek could you please point out why I should stay away from JQM grids?

Comment: My first case for that is: you don't need one. It only takes a few lines of CSS to make one. Besides that, other grids make you think about columns too early. You name things like column_4 row_4th and stuff. The content should be separate from the style.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Un2k3/   I still don't know what you want to happen when the window resizes. you just have one layout here. Are the purple and green configurations on the same page or are they variations? Why don't you tell us more about what you want?

Comment: @user1027620 mentioned bootstrap in my answer but had pasted wrong code, just updated the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can use bootstrap and its grid system (the following example uses bootstrap3)

http://jsfiddle.net/fAPhz/

**HTML**

```
    <!-- JQM Pages -->
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>page1</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container1 col-xs-6">
            <div class="top-box col-xs-12"></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box1 col-xs-6 "></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box2 col-xs-6 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container2 col-xs-6">
            <div class="top-box col-xs-12"></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box1 col-xs-6 "></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box2 col-xs-6 "></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container1,.container2 {
    background-color:blue;
    padding:5px;
}
.top-box {
    background-color:pink;
    height:100px;
}
.bottom-box {
    height:50px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.bottom-box1 {
    background-color:red;
}
.bottom-box2 {
    background-color:brown;
}
```

If you wish to have *n* containers then just rename the *container1* and *container2* to something else like *block-container* (not just *container* since it is used by the bootstrap3 grid system) and use it as many times as you need but always take care of the *col-xs-** values e.g. if you had 3 containers (12col grid system 12/3=4) then you would make it `class="block-container col-xs-4"`.

**Solution 2**

Or you can try with plain css and html. In order to have complete control over any resolution you should use media queries. In this example i show a rough implementation with the use of media queries to support small resolutions.

*This is just a start to work on, if you really need this i can elaborate further.*

http://jsfiddle.net/DRZes/

```
<!-- JQM Pages -->
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>page1</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="top-box"></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box1"></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="top-box"></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box1"></div>
            <div class="bottom-box bottom-box2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container1, .container2 {
    padding:5px;
    width:48%;
    background-color:blue;
}
.container1 {
    float:left;
}
.container2 {
    float:right;
}
.top-box {
    background-color:pink;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.bottom-box {
    height:50px;
    width:49%;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.bottom-box1 {
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}
.bottom-box2 {
    float:right;
    background-color:brown;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .container1, .container2 {
        width:47%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .container1, .container2 {
       width:46%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 280px) {
    .container1, .container2 {
       width:45%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 200px) {
    .container1, .container2 {
       width:40%;
    }
}
```